# Ways to download multiple patches in Android Application?

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager, apk-expansion-files

I'm pretty new to Android so excuse me for uncertainty.

I have been reading quite a lot about Android lately and have come across the idea of using expansion files with them (.obb) and their use as patches. But I guess there is only one patch file which can be uploaded with any Android Application on the Play Store. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

I have an idea which can help minimise the app size and give users full flexibility to control what they need. When you first install my app, it will have all the basic functions required for the app to work (example: code for performing a specific function) Then if the user tries to perform another option, the app will connect online and will know how to handle the event. (This will be worked out later)

But, in the settings menu I want to give users a choice. They can check all the modules they want offline, so that my app doesn't need to connect online for those particular modules. If they check, for example, two modules, then their .java files will be downloaded and their data will be used next time instead of the app going online.

I want to know if this is possible or not. If yes, how and where do I make my app download the additional .java files and how do I implement their inclusion in the current app. Is there a workaround for this flexibility?

Comment if you need more details.

Answer (score 0):

Exist 2 types of expansion packs:

```
The **main expansion file** is the primary expansion file for additional resources required by your application.

The **patch expansion file** is optional and intended for small updates to the main expansion file.
```

You can use the two expansion files any way you wish

But... there can be only two expansion files for your application at a time.

Comment: Umm... I know that. I was asking ways to provide more than one patch. Any ideas?

Comment: I say it. "there can be only two expansion files for your application at a time." Check Documentation.

Comment: Okay.. For example I have a java file located at some URL. How can I import that file to my existing project during run time?